# REST Framework применяемость

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Есть такой фреймворк `Django`, который позволяет создавать приложение в виде `html`-страничек.

А есть дополнение к `Django` - `Django REST Framework`, который позволяет реализовать интерфейс в виде `REST API` и по запросам `GET, POST` получать `JSON`.

Так вот - вопрос, правильно ли я понимаю, что эти две технологии обычно совмещаются друг с другом в одном приложении и изначально пишется приложение на простом `Django`, чтобы все работало, а затем уже дополняют `Django REST Framework`, чтобы добавить дополнительный интерфейс взаимодействия?

Comment: Да, DRF - это надстройка над django. Ничего не мешает разрабатывать REST API и без DRF,  DRF - это просто набор инструментов для удобства

Comment: @Александр вопрос немного в другом, я бы хотел реализовать REST API при помощи DRF, но если я его реализую, нужно ли приложению делать стандартный джанговский интерфейс в виде html-страничек, или обычно если реализуют DRF, то html-страницы не используют и наоборот?

Comment: @Анонимныйволшебник как разработчикам захочется, так и делают

Comment: @Александр а какой в принципе смысл делать только drf без html? для чего это может использоваться?

Comment: Например, как бэкенд для мобилок

Comment: @Александр понял, спасибо